# p:dataTable solid row name jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How i can do that kind of table using `p:dataTable` primefaces showcase. I want that column name and row name be steady always, only data in table can be changed.

My table picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example here is simple dataTable code. You can adjust style in CSS or style argument, if you want grey headers.

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}">

<p:column style="background-color: grey">
   <h:outputLabel>row name</h:outputLabel>
</p:column>

  <p:column headerText="column name">  
  </p:column>

<p:column headerText="column name">  
  </p:column>

<p:column headerText="column name">  
  </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: That was very helpful but how i can add couple of <p:column style="background-color: grey">
   <h:outputLabel>row name</h:outputLabel>
</p:column>
with columns, one under another? When i write this code:

    '<p:column style="background-color: grey">
       <h:outputLabel>row name</h:outputLabel>
    </p:column>

      <p:column headerText="column name">  
      </p:column>
    <p:column style="background-color: grey">
        <h:outputLabel>row name</h:outputLabel>
    </p:column>

      <p:column headerText="column name">  
      </p:column>'

everything is in one line.